# Submitting an array of checkbox values with PHP post method

Tags: php

Im trying to email a list of checkbox values using `wp_mail` the result of my code IS sending the email

but the value returns as an array.. I understand why, but I am not sure how to breakdown the array, I dont see how I can implement a foreach here.

**PHP:**

```
  //checkmarks post variable
       $checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];

  //php mailer variables
       $to = get_option('admin_email');
       $subject = "Someone sent a message from ".get_bloginfo('name');
       $headers = 'From: '. $email . "rn" .

         $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $checks, $headers);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">

    <input type="submit">

<li class="option table selected">
    <div class="option-checkbox">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="personalization_result[memory_0]">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="personalization_result[memory_0]" id="personalization_result_memory_0" checked="checked">
    </div>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="option table selected">
    <div class="option-checkbox">
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="personalization_result[memory_1]">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="personalization_result[memory_1]" id="personalization_result_memory_1" checked="checked">
    </div>
    </div>
</li>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you call the `wp_mail` function, you need to process your `$checks` variable and turn it into a string, e.g.:

```
   $checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];
   $checkString = ''
   foreach ($checks as $k=>$v) {
       //some code to build up $checkString
   }
```

You'd then obviously have to use `$checkString` instead of `$checks` in your `wp_mail` call . . .

Alternatively, if you don't care about the keys, you could do something like:

```
     $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, implode("|",$checks), $headers);
```

Then you'd end up with something like "0|1"

Comment: Thanks for the answer I am going to implement it now... After I posted this question I had to run somewhere... Ill post back with my result..